# constructing bada form from other than normal res folder

Tags: bada

I have a bada project setup for HVGA resolution. My sdk doesn't allow me to edit the layout files in the HVGA mode when placed in the SCREEN-SIZE-NORmAL folder. I can create and edit  form layouts int 480x800 folder. So how can I specify the resourse id while constructing the form?
i.e. what would be the resource Id of the a form layout in 480x800 folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, its not possible. The sdk being used needed to be updated in order to get the HVGA layouts working.